# Adding Date and Time values in R

Tags: r

I have the following kind of data in my datafile

```
DriveNo     Date and Time
12         2017-01-31 23:00:00     //Start time of a trip for Driver12
134        2017-01-31 23:00:01
12         2017-01-31 23:10:00     //End time ( 10 min trip)
345        (some date/time)
12         2017-01-31 23:20:00     //Start Time 
12         2017-01-31 23:35:00     //End Time (15 min trip)
 .
 .
 .
```

millions of similar data follow

The total number of data is around 3 million. Now, I need to get the time driven my each of the drivers(there are around 500 drivers).My ideal output would be like

```
DriveNo    TotalTimeDriven
12          35mins
134         ........(in days/hours/mins)
.
.
```

(for all other Drivers as well)

Above, DriveNo 12 has four entries, suggesting start and end of two rides.Is there an efficient R way to do this?

Comment: Group by `DriveNo`, then take `diff(range(DateTime))`. In dplyr, `df %>% group_by(DriveNo) %>% summarise(TimeDriven = diff(range(DateTime)))`, though `aggregate` or data.table would work fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range` returns the maximum and minimum, and `diff` subtracts sequential numbers in a vector, so you could just do

```
aggregate(DateTime ~ DriveNo, df, function(x){diff(range(x))})
##   DriveNo DateTime
## 1      12      10 
## 2     134       0
```

or in dplyr,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(DriveNo) %>% summarise(TimeDriven = diff(range(DateTime)))
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##   DriveNo TimeDriven
##     <int>     <time>
## 1      12    10 mins
## 2     134     0 mins
```

or in data.table,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(TimeDriven = diff(range(DateTime))), by = DriveNo]
##    DriveNo TimeDriven
## 1:      12    10 mins
## 2:     134     0 mins
```

To change the units, it may be simpler to call `difftime` directly.

---

Data

```
df <- structure(list(DriveNo = c(12L, 134L, 12L), DateTime = structure(c(1485921600, 
    1485921601, 1485922200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L), .Names = c("DriveNo", "DateTime"))
```

---

For the edit, you can make a variable identifying starts and stops, reshape, and summarise with `difftime` and `sum`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47)

drives <- data_frame(DriveNo = sample(rep(1:5, 4)), 
                     DateTime = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-04-13 12:00:00"), 
                                    by = '10 min', length.out = 20))

drives %>% str()
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ DriveNo : int  5 3 4 3 5 1 1 2 3 5 ...
#>  $ DateTime: POSIXct, format: "2017-04-13 12:00:00" "2017-04-13 12:10:00" ...

elapsed <- drives %>% 
    group_by(DriveNo) %>% 
    mutate(event = rep(c('start', 'stop'), n() / 2), 
           i = cumsum(event == 'start')) %>% 
    spread(event, DateTime) %>% 
    summarise(TimeDriven = sum(difftime(stop, start, units = 'mins')))

elapsed
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   DriveNo TimeDriven
#>     <int>     <time>
#> 1       1    60 mins
#> 2       2   110 mins
#> 3       3   120 mins
#> 4       4   130 mins
#> 5       5    80 mins
```

It would be faster to index by recycled Boolean vectors, but in dplyr they get unclassed at some point. In data.table,

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(47)

drives <- data.table(DriveNo = sample(rep(1:5, 4)), 
                     DateTime = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-04-13 12:00:00"), 
                                    by = '10 min', length.out = 20))

elapsed <- drives[, .(TimeDriven = sum(difftime(DateTime[c(FALSE, TRUE)], 
                                                DateTime[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
                                                units = 'mins'))), 
                  keyby = DriveNo]

elapsed
#>    DriveNo TimeDriven
#> 1:       1    60 mins
#> 2:       2   110 mins
#> 3:       3   120 mins
#> 4:       4   130 mins
#> 5:       5    80 mins
```

or in base,

```r
set.seed(47)

drives <- data.frame(DriveNo = sample(rep(1:5, 4)), 
                     DateTime = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-04-13 12:00:00"), 
                                    by = '10 min', length.out = 20))

elapsed <- aggregate(DateTime ~ DriveNo, drives, 
                     function(x){sum(difftime(x[c(FALSE, TRUE)], x[c(TRUE, FALSE)], units = 'mins'))})

elapsed
#>   DriveNo DateTime
#> 1       1      60 
#> 2       2     110 
#> 3       3     120 
#> 4       4     130 
#> 5       5      80
```

All forms will likely have issues if there are an odd number of times for a driver, which is not possible under the assumptions given. If it is, more cleaning is necessary.

Comment: Minor point: it might be desirable to have some other value in cases of an incomplete trip rather than zero... NA (of class difftime) or time diff based on time the data was pulled.

Comment: @alistaire df %>% group_by(DriveNo) %>% summarise(TimeDriven = diff(range(DateTime)))                                                                                 will only provide me with the Time driven of the first and last entry (range ). However, the dataset has many entries for the same driver. As i mentioned in the question, there are just 500 drivers , but the data is around 3 million.

Comment: Your example result implies you should end up with one row for each driver. Are some of the timestamps starts and others stops? If so, how are they differentiated? Position? By the sound of it, you need to edit your example to be a sufficiently representative subset, which apparently what's there now is not.

Comment: @alistaire Yes, i would end up with one row for each driver. For start/stop, the first entry for Driver 1 would be start and the second entry would be stop. The third entry would be start again and fourth stop and so on.. So, if the first and second have a difference of 10 mins and third and fourth with 15, my resulting value should be 25.

Comment: You need to edit your question with sufficient data and the corresponding desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Data table solution:-

```
# Sample data    
df <- data.table(DriveNo = c(12, 134, 12, 134), Time = c("2017-01-31 23:00:00", "2017-01-31 23:00:01", "2017-01-31 23:10:00", "2017-01-31 23:20:01"))

df[, duration := max(as.POSIXct(Time)) - min(as.POSIXct(Time)), by = DriveNo]

df
DriveNo                Time duration
1:      12 2017-01-31 23:00:00  10 mins
2:     134 2017-01-31 23:00:01  20 mins
3:      12 2017-01-31 23:10:00  10 mins
4:     134 2017-01-31 23:20:01  20 mins
```

Comment: You could alternately perhaps do `DT[order(time), difftime(time[1], time[2], units = "min"), by=g]` or similar.

Comment: @Frank That would only work if there are two times. @ahly It would likely make more sense to collapse the groups: `df[, Time := as.POSIXct(Time)][, .(duration = max(Time) - min(Time)), by = DriveNo]`

Comment: @alistaire Yeah, I agree re collapsing, but don't see any reason to believe the data should have more than two entries. Certainly I've seen data sets like this that reliably have 1-2 entries. For the case of more entries, there is some efficiency improvement from `DT[order(t), .(first(t), last(t)), by=g][, diff := V2 - V1]` in terms of how the computations get done (or alternately with min and max and not sorting) thanks to the stuff mentioned in `?GForce`.